# sql server 2008 dbmail error sp_send_dbmail - cannot insert null value into 'last_mod_user' in table sysmail_mailitems

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

Our dbmail got hosed and I'm trying to resolve the issue.

I've recently recreated sp_send_dbmail, but am not getting an odd error regarding a null value in last_mod_user column in table msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems (error 515)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`last_mod_user` in `msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems` should have a default defined on it. Has that gone missing on your install?

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sysmail_mailitems] ADD  DEFAULT (suser_sname()) FOR [last_mod_user]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my [msdb's [sp_send_dbmail] stored proc on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ZHgXcjZ1). Taken from SQL Server 2008 SP1.

The `INSERT` statement curiously doesn't include a value for `last_mod_user`! Line 364 on PasteBin.

Your error sounds correct; the field `last_mod_user` is defined as non nullable.

[image]